# sanity error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'config')

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css, internal-server-error, sanity

I've started a next.js project with sanity.io. The setup is successfully completed. Npm run dev spins out the app on localhost successfully. But the problem is when I start the sanity studio.
The following err occurs.

[image: the err while running : sanity start command]

This is my package.json

[image: package.json file]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and take the appropriate [action](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73040459/edit). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

creating `tailwind.config.js` file helped me in the similar case.
content can be simple as that:

```
module.exports = {
  content: [],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a "postcss.config.js" just comment out or delete the "tailwind css: {}".

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and i prefer use the steps in the tailwind started page
just bcs it will handle any additional steps.
this is the page : https://tailwindcss.com/docs/installation/using-postcss

and i think the only step that you need to fix yours was
run this in your project: **npx tailwindcss init**

of course as the previous comment adding the file manually will fixed too.